# Leaflet.js - can't get my current location on some browsers

Tags: apache, http, browser, geolocation, leaflet

I have made this [application](http://floratvedras.cm-tvedras.pt) using Leaflet.js with these plugins: [MarkerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), [Leaflet Map Fullscreen](https://github.com/brunob/leaflet.fullscreen), it's hosted in a Linux server, HTTP apache2.

For some reason, I can't get my current location on the following browsers:

- Mozilla Firefox (latest version)
- Google Chrome (latest version)
- Microsoft Edge

In IE, it gives me the popup to give permission to locate myself, and it works... only once. If I try to locate myself again it behaves like the other browsers above.

And, if I open the link in Instagram dm's it works just fine...

[image: request to get current location][image: and locates just fine]

It works also in localhost or if I use location guard browser extension to make my location a fixed point.

What's causing this issue? Is it because it isn't https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to switch to https if you want to support geolocation on most if not all modern browsers.

For [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)

> Starting with Chrome 50, Chrome no longer supports obtaining the
>   user's location using the HTML5 Geolocation API from pages delivered
>   by non-secure connections. This means that the page that's making the
>   Geolocation API call must be served from a secure context such as
>   HTTPS.

For [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

> This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS) [...]

And according to the [nice support grid on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Browser_compatibility), Opera and Safari should also require https to enable geolocation.

Comment: yeah i thought so, i have reached that conclusion too but i wanted some feedback from the SO community so i won't make any mistake, thank you alot for your time and have a nice day.